# $\text{char}(K) = p > 0$, $E/K$ elliptic curve with $j(E) \notin \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$, follows that $\text{End}(E) = \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $\text{char}(K) = p > 0$, and let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve with $j(E) \notin \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$.

Does it follow that $\text{End}(E) = \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Silverman's "Arithmetic of elliptic curves", Exercise 5.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This seems to be due to Deuring. There are various proofs. You'll find a proof, for example, in Mumford's *Abelian Varieties*, page 217.